# why linux says cannot stat

Tags: linux

I am in some directory on my linux hosting. I want to move all files from relative subdir1 to dir2, dir2 being under root dir. So I type

```
mv ./subdir1/*.* ~/dir2/
```

but it doesn't work it says it

```
cannot stat './subdir1/*.*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just `./subdir1/*` and see if that works. Running -v with the mv might help for debugging.

Comment: There probably aren't any files that match *.* in this directory.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, you want to move **all** files, then the pattern `*.*` is not correct because you are asking for all files that have an extension (try executing `ls *.*`).

The correct command would be:

```
mv ./subdir1/* ~/dir2/
```

If this does not work, then probably the administrator disabled the shell "pathname expansion" mechanism using the `-f` switch (see `man sh`).

Answer (score 1):

subdir1 either is empty, or a broken symlink or doesn't exist or there are no files in it with dots in their names.